# Change Everything to Black And White (Applying Blending to View Background Colour)

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

## Result:

[image]

The middle image with the alert box popup is the result I want to achieve.

When popup an alert box, everything changes to black and white. The way to achieve this in design is to adding a layer on top with background colour black and blending mode hue.

So in order to implement this, here is what I tried.

I tried to add a view on top (Transparent background). Inside that view, I draw a rectangle with blend mode hue.

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
  let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
  UIColor.black.setFill()
  context?.setBlendMode(.hue)

  let rect = rect
  context?.addRect(rect)
  context?.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)
}
```

The **UIView** has constraint to set to full screen. However that just result a black rectangle.

Any hint on how to achieve this?

Comment: This is neat, but is there any reason that the system default of dimming the background is insufficient? I tend not to like when developers decide that there's something wrong with the system defaults.

Comment: @BallpointBen Actually the whole point for me to do this is to see if this is possible and increase my knowledge and skill bases. I don't actually want to implement this. I searched and didn't see any solution related to this. Thanks to matt for the answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a blend mode with what is *behind* the view. Blend mode is about drawing *into* this context.

To achieve what you're describing, you would have to take a snapshot of the current view controller's view and draw it in black-and-white into your context.

The usual thing, however, is just to set the [`tintAdjustmentMode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622555-tintadjustmentmode). That is what a real alert view does.